# Draw an NSWindow over the entire screen, from corner to corner, including the menu bar and dock

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nswindow

I want to draw an NSWindow for an overlay application that completely covers the users screen - from corner to corner. I've got a borderloss, non activating panel that takes over the entire page.

```swift
import Foundation
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

class FullScreenPanel: NSPanel {
  override func constrainFrameRect(_ frameRect: NSRect, to screen: NSScreen?) -> NSRect {
    return frameRect
  }

}
final class Panel: FullScreenPanel, NSWindowDelegate {
  init(contentRect: NSRect, backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
    super.init(
      contentRect: contentRect,
      styleMask: [.borderless, .nonactivatingPanel],
      backing: backing,
      defer: flag
    )

    self.level = .mainMenu + 3
    self.collectionBehavior.insert(.fullScreenAuxiliary) // Allows the panel to appear in a fullscreen space
    self.collectionBehavior.insert(.canJoinAllSpaces)
    self.titleVisibility = .hidden
    self.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    self.isMovable = false
    self.isMovableByWindowBackground = false
    self.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
    self.isOpaque = false
    self.delegate = self
  }

  func windowDidResignKey(_ notification: Notification) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      appDelegate?.hideWindow()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm instantiating this with the `NSScreen.main.frame` CGRect

```swift
mainWindow = Panel(
    contentRect: NSScreen.main!.frame,
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

However, when the window shows up, it still shows up under the menu bar. The `constrainFrameRect` function shows that somewhere internally the y value of the frame goes from 0 to to `-44`.

The window should also *not* trigger the native fullscreen effect, where it becomes a new "Desktop" that you can swipe between.

Comment: Take a look at [NSApplicationPresentationOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationpresentationoptions).

Answer (score 2):

1. I think that you use `NSPanel` class incorrectly. [Official Documentation for `NSPanel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspanel/):

   > #### NSPanel
   >
   > A special kind of window that typically performs a function that is auxiliary to the main window.

   Your window is probably main (Because it takes up the whole screen and is the only visible one), so the `NSPanel` is not necessary, just use generic `NSWindow`.
2. Use an `NSWindowController` for better code organisation.
3. Use

   ```swift
   NSApplication.shared.presentationOptions = [.hideDock, .hideMenuBar]
   ```

   to hide the dock and menu bar completely and

   ```swift
   NSApplication.shared.presentationOptions = [.autoHideDock, .autoHideMenuBar]
   ```

   to make them appear when you hover over the position where they have been by default.

***Warning! This code might block your whole screen. Consider adding an exit button or a shortcut (In the current version you can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus on another window). In the worst case you must reboot your computer by holding down the power button.***

**Code:**

```swift
class FullScreenWindowController: NSWindowController {
    let viewController = FullScreenViewController()

    init() {
        super.init(window: NSWindow(contentViewController: viewController))
        
        // Remove the window header
        window?.styleMask = .borderless
        
        window?.setFrame(window!.screen!.frame, display: true)
        
        // Dock and Menu Bar are completely inaccessible
        // NSApplication.shared.presentationOptions = [.hideDock, .hideMenuBar]
        
        // Dock and Menu Bar will automatically hide when not needed
        NSApplication.shared.presentationOptions = [.autoHideDock, .autoHideMenuBar]
        
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

To use the above class, just create an instance of it:

```swift
let fullScreenWindowController = FullScreenWindowController()
```

Also I used this view controller:

```swift
class FullScreenViewController: NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let label = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Full Screen Window")
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 48)
        view = label
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

OK I'm pretty noob in this however you could try the below (please don't flame if not working, it's just a suggestion lol I can delete the answer given if you hate it)

```
final class Panel: FullScreenPanel, NSWindowDelegate {
  init(contentRect: NSRect, backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
    let menuBarHeight = NSStatusBar.system.thickness
    let adjustedContentRect = NSRect(x: contentRect.origin.x,
                                     y: contentRect.origin.y + menuBarHeight,
                                     width: contentRect.size.width,
                                     height: contentRect.size.height - menuBarHeight)
    
    super.init(
      contentRect: adjustedContentRect,
      styleMask: [.borderless, .nonactivatingPanel],
      backing: backing,
      defer: flag
    )

    // Rest of your code...
  }

  // Rest of your code...
}
```